# Validation of a drop down list in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a form in PHP. I have instructions not to change the form itself (The names of the fields for example) and in it there is a drop down list with this:
    `<option value=""></option>`

I tried to validate with this :

```
if (!isset($_POST['cboproduit'])){
$message.= "Vous devez sélectionner un téléphone <br />";}
```

but since there is a value with nothing in it, if I submit the form with the empty value it just saves an empty value.

How can I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking if the variable is set, you need to check if it's not empty:

```
if (!isset($_POST['cboproduit']) || $_POST['cboproduit'] === '') {
    $message .= "Vous devez sélectionner un téléphone <br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer ! Really appreciated :D

Comment: It is worth noting that such check has one probably unexpected side effect: it treats string `"0"` as empty. Here is [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [proof](http://ideone.com/ateuBE).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of `isset` as `empty` also checks if the variable exists or not:

```
 if (empty($_POST['cboproduit'])){
    $message.= "Vous devez sélectionner un téléphone <br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Different functions check different things about a variable. According to the documentation:

- [`isset()`](http://be1.php.net/isset): Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.
- [`empty()`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
- [`array_key_exists()`](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php): returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array

So in your case, `if (empty($_POST['cboproduit']))` seems the best way to proceed. It will detect if the value was somehow not transmitted (someone could edit the form in their browser before submitting it) or the empty option was selected.

(Note that this means that there is no way to determine the difference between a variable that does not exist and a variable that is `null`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but empty may not work for you because the value attribute of `<option value=""></option>` may be set to 0 for the first element (1 as the second and so on) and then this would mean that you could never delete the 0th element as empty checks for 0 and also for empty

```
if (empty($_POST['cboproduit'])){
    $message.= "Vous devez sélectionner un téléphone <br />";
 }
```